# how to sum up matrices in multiple files using bash or awk

Tags: bash, awk

If I have an arbitrary number of files, say n files, and each file contains a matrix,  how can I use bash or awk to sum up all the matrices in each file and get an output?

For example, if n=3, and I have these 3 files with the following contents

$ cat mat1.txt

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

$cat mat2.txt

```
1 1 1
1 1 1
1 1 1
```

$ cat mat3.txt

```
2 2 2 
2 2 2
2 2 2
```

I want to get this output:

$ cat output.txt

```
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Is there a simple one liner to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) total[FNR","i]+=$i;} END{for (j=1;j<=FNR;j++) {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%3i ",total[j","i]; print "";}}' mat1.txt mat2.txt mat3.txt
  4   5   6 
  7   8   9 
 10  11  12
```

This will automatically adjust to different size matrices.  I don't believe that I have used any GNU features so this should be portable to OSX and elsewhere.

#### How it works:

This command reads from each line from each matrix, one matrix at a time.

- For each line read, the following command is executed:

  ```
  for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) total[FNR","i]+=$i
  ```

  This loops over every column on the line and adds it to the array `total`.

  GNU `awk` has multidimensional arrays but, for portability, they are not used here.  awk's arrays are associative and this creates an index from the file's line number, `FNR`, and the column number `i`, by combining them together with a comma.  The result should be portable.
- After all the matrices have been read, the results in `total` are printed:

  ```
  END{for (j=1;j<=FNR;j++) {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%3i ",total[j","i]; print ""}}
  ```

  Here, `j` loops over each line up to the total number of lines, `FNR`.  Then `i` loops over each column up to the total number of columns, `NF`.  For each row and column, the total is printed via `printf "%3i ",total[j","i]`.  This prints the total as a 3-character-wide integer.  If you numbers are float or are bigger, adjust the format accordingly.

  At the end of each row, the `print ""` statement causes a newline character to be printed.

Comment: Replacing `mat1.txt mat2.txt mat3.txt` at the end by `mat*.txt` is more concise and also works (for me).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` with `paste`:

```
awk -v n=3 '{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) printf "%s%s", ($i + $(i+n) + $(i+n*2)), 
            (i==n)?ORS:OFS}' <(paste mat{1,2,3}.txt)
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Comment: Nice use of paste. You might want to pass `-v n=3` to awk

Comment: @anubhava Smart use of paste. I'm curious why you've used `awk <(...)` rather than the more common `... | awk`, would you like to comment please?

Comment: @gboffi: `<(...)` is called process substitution and that is considered better than using pipes in BASH.

Comment: I was genuinely interested in why YOU have preferred process substitution to a pipe. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @gboffi: Mostly performance reasons, [see this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127645/performance-differences-between-pipelines-and-process-substitution)

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk has multi-dimensional arrays.

```
gawk '
    {
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
            m[i][FNR] += $i
    } 
    END {
        for (y=1; y<=FNR; y++) {
            for (x=1; x<=NF; x++)
                printf "%d ", m[x][y]
            print ""
        }
    }
' mat{1,2,3}.txt
```